# Parsing command line for execve() error. Plain C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, argv

I'm new to C pointers and trying to execute process with command line and obtain its pid. Any of system(), sh(), etc, that use command line doesn't return pid, so I desided to use execve(). But it needs command line to be parsed to string array.

I found some existing solutions, but I could not make any to work. So, I wrote mine own. It works in my test program, but causes segmentation error in real one.
Can somebody tell me, where I am wrong?
Code is:

```
void cmdline_to_argv(const char* cmd_line, char*** argv, int* argc){
    int len, i, count, spc;
    char *s,*d;
    /* make a copy to play with */
    char *cmd_line1 = strdup(cmd_line);

    /* count items to deal with and trim multiple spaces */
    d = s = cmd_line1; spc = 1; count = 0; len=strlen(cmd_line1);
    for (i=0; i<len;i++,s++) {
        switch (*s) {
        case ' ':
            if (spc) continue;
            *d++ = '\0'; /* replace spaces with zeroes */
            spc = 1;
            break;
        default:
            if (spc) { count++; spc = 0; }
            *d++ = *s;
        }
    }
    (*d++) = '\0'; /* line termination */
    /* reallocate copy to correct size */
    cmd_line1 = realloc( cmd_line1, d - cmd_line1);
    /* allocate array of poiters */
    *argv = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (count+1));
    argv[count] = NULL;
    /* scan line again to find all lines starts and register */
    s = cmd_line1;
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        (*argv)[i] = s;
        while (*(s++)) ;
    }
    *argc = count;
}
```

and there is how I call it:

```
char **chargv = NULL;
int chargc;

/* parse line to argument array */
cmdline_to_argv(cmdline, &chargv, &chargc);
```

I think all the trouble here with pointer operations where I allocate array and write to it. How to do it correct?

Answer (score 2):

The question is closed. Solution is found. The tricky pointer declaration syntax solved. Here is the working one.

Thanks to All. :-|

```
 void cmdline_to_argv(const char* cmd_line, char ***argv, int* argc){
    int i, spc;
    size_t len;
    char *s,*d;
    /* make a copy to play with */
    char *cmd_line1 = strdup(cmd_line);

    /* count items to deal with and trim multiple spaces */
    d = s = cmd_line1; spc = 1; *argc = 0; len=strlen(cmd_line1);
    for (i=0; i<len;i++,s++) {
        switch (*s) {
        case ' ':
            if (spc) continue;
            *d++ = '\0'; /* replace spaces with zeroes */
            spc = 1;
            break;
        default:
            if (spc) { (*argc)++; spc = 0; }
            *d++ = *s;
        }
    }
    (*d++) = '\0'; /* line termination */
    /* calc actual size */
    len = d - cmd_line1;
    /* allocate array of poiters */
    *argv = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ((*argc)+1) + len);
    (*argv)[*argc] = (char*) NULL;
    d = (char*) &(*argv)[(*argc)+1];
    memmove(d, cmd_line1, len);
    free(cmd_line1);
    cmd_line1 = d;
    /* scan line again to find all lines starts and register */
    for (i=0; i<*argc; i++) {
        (*argv)[i] = d;
        while (*(d++)) ;
    }
}

/* deallocate array and strings */
void free_argv(char ***argv) {
    free(*argv); /* strings laying together at once after pointers array */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked here https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getpid.2.html  I believe what you want is getpid() although maybe you are asking something more.

Comment: Thanks. But getpid() works in current process only, and the child is not my own, so I can't use getpid() within it. Pid of child must be known in the parent process, after it starts the child. Maybe, there is another way to obtain pid after system() call or something like it, that does not need array but single line?

Comment: So you are trying to get the pid of the child in the parent after you fork? If you are then fork returns the pid of the child to the parent.

Comment: Yes! I really use fork() to get pid and then override forked child with another process image with execve() call. That's why I need to convert line to array for execve(). The converting routine shown above is my question. It glitches, and I need to know why.